# How to Copy highlighted text in Browser from C#

Tags: c#, browser, hotkeys, keystroke

I have C# based winform application which registred for an Hotkey-Event.

Once it get the event for Hotkey, it will copy the selected or highlighted data from current focus window.

**To Copy Data :**

1. Using clipboard

   Using `SendKey.SendWait` send `CTRL + C` Keystroke and get data from clipboard.
2. Using UI AutomationElement

   Using AutomationElement get Focus windows element. and using its TextPattern get selected data.

**Problems**

1. Above Solution works for NotePad,WordPAd,MS Word.
2. I m not able to selected data from Browser, Pdf kind of application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you examined all the DataFormats returned by IDataObject, to check for the data returned?

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    // Declares an IDataObject to hold the data returned from the clipboard.
    // Retrieves the data from the clipboard.
    IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

    // Determines whether the data is in a format you can use.
    if(iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) {
       // Yes it is, so display it in a text box.
       textBox2.Text = (String)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text); 
    }
    else {
       // No it is not.
       textBox2.Text = "Could not retrieve data off the clipboard.";
    }
 }
```

Full description at of above code at
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdataobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Link below is a list of all 22 DataFormats available, and DataFormats.RTF (pdf), DataFormats.Unicode (pdf,browser)(only text) and DataFormats.HTML(browser) are likely candidates for you.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats(v=vs.110).aspx

How to: Retrieve Data from the Clipboard
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2thcsx4(v=vs.110).aspx